# Is there a way to install TypeScript in Visual Studio with IE8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I'm trying to get TypeScript (0.9.5) installed into Visual Studio 2012 on my work PC, which only has IE8 (I know, I know, it's a horrible state of affairs...).

The installation process will not complete, and says that I should install IE10 first.

Does anyone have any workarounds that might let me install it whilst keeping IE8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Some people have had success](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1975) setting the `svcVersion` registry value under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer` to `"10.0.9200.16384"`. Obviously this is crazy unsupported, but it might work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Ryan, my google-foo failed me on that one!